# Oracle apex logo version 4.2.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, region

i created a logo for my application, and it's showing up fine in all pages. How do I put the page title right next to the logo (on the right side). If there's a way to display the logo plus the actual page name, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to edit the page template to do that. Put `#TITLE#` in the Body section, perhaps just after where you see `#LOGO#` - e.g.:

[image]

*Note: your theme may have different code, this is just an example.*